# i^(i^i) - Why is the solution single-valued (according to wolframalpha)

Tags: complex-analysis

I was looking for:

$${i^{\left( {{i^i}} \right)}} = ?
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbbjxAHX
% garmWu51MyVXgaruavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garqqtubsr4rNCHbGe
% aGqi-C0de9vqqrpepy0dbbL8F4rqqqFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm
% 0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9ad
% biqaceGaciGaciaabiqaceGadaabaaGcbaGaamyAamaaCaaaleqaba
% WaaeWabeaacaWGPbWaaWbaaWqabeaacaWGPbaaaaWccaGLOaGaayzk
% aaaaaOGaeyypa0Jaai4paaaa!3985!
$$

First I calculated i^i with the formular for generalised powers:

$${i^i} = {e^{i \cdot \ln \left( i \right)}} = {e^{i \cdot i \cdot \left( {{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} + 2\pi n} \right)}} = {e^{ - \left( {{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} + 2\pi n} \right)}} = {e^{ - {\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} - 2\pi n}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbbjxAHX
% garmWu51MyVXgaruavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garqqtubsr4rNCHbGe
% aGqi-C0de9vqqrpepy0dbbL8F4rqqqFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm
% 0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9ad
% biqaceGaciGaciaabiqaceGadaabaaGcbaGaamyAamaaCaaaleqaba
% GaamyAaaaakiabg2da9iaadwgadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadMgacqGHflY1
% ciGGSbGaaiOBamaabmqabaGaamyAaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaakiabg2
% da9iaadwgadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadMgacqGHflY1caWGPbGaeyyXIC9a
% aeWabeaadaWcbaadbaGaeqiWdahabaGaaGOmaaaaliabgUcaRiaaik
% dacqaHapaCcaWGUbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaaaOGaeyypa0Jaamyzamaa
% CaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0YaaeWabeaadaWcbaadbaGaeqiWdahabaGaaG
% OmaaaaliabgUcaRiaaikdacqaHapaCcaWGUbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaa
% aOGaeyypa0JaamyzamaaCaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0YaaSqaaWqaaiabec
% 8aWbqaaiaaikdaaaWccqGHsislcaaIYaGaeqiWdaNaamOBaaaaaaa!6567!
$$

I put the solution in:

$${i^{\left( {{i^i}} \right)}}{\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}{i^{\left[ {{e^{ - {\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} - 2\pi n}}} \right]}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbbjxAHX
% garmWu51MyVXgaruavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garqqtubsr4rNCHbGe
% aGqi-C0de9vqqrpepy0dbbL8F4rqqqFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm
% 0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9ad
% biqaceGaciGaciaabiqaceGadaabaaGcbaGaamyAamaaCaaaleqaba
% WaaeWabeaacaWGPbWaaWbaaWqabeaacaWGPbaaaaWccaGLOaGaayzk
% aaaaaOGaaeiiaiabg2da9iaabccacaWGPbWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWade
% qaaiaadwgadaahaaadbeqaaiabgkHiTmaaleaabaGaeqiWdahabaGa
% aGOmaaaacqGHsislcaaIYaGaeqiWdaNaamOBaaaaaSGaay5waiaaw2
% faaaaaaaa!4609!
$$

I used the formular for generalised powers again:

$${i^{\left( {{i^i}} \right)}}{\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}{e^{\left[ {{e^{ - {\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} - 2\pi n}} \cdot \ln \left( i \right)} \right]}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbbjxAHX
% garmWu51MyVXgaruavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garqqtubsr4rNCHbGe
% aGqi-C0de9vqqrpepy0dbbL8F4rqqqFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm
% 0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9ad
% biqaceGaciGaciaabiqaceGadaabaaGcbaGaamyAamaaCaaaleqaba
% WaaeWabeaacaWGPbWaaWbaaWqabeaacaWGPbaaaaWccaGLOaGaayzk
% aaaaaOGaaeiiaiabg2da9iaabccacaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWade
% qaaiaadwgadaahaaadbeqaaiabgkHiTmaaleaabaGaeqiWdahabaGa
% aGOmaaaacqGHsislcaaIYaGaeqiWdaNaamOBaaaaliabgwSixlGacY
% gacaGGUbWaaeWabeaacaWGPbaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaacaGLBbGaayzx
% aaaaaaaa!4CAB!
$$

Last I calculated the logarithm:

$${i^{\left( {{i^i}} \right)}}{\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}{e^{\left[ {{e^{ - {\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} - 2\pi n}} \cdot i \cdot \left( {{\textstyle{\pi  \over 2}} + 2\pi k} \right)} \right]}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbbjxAHX
% garmWu51MyVXgaruavP1wzZbItLDhis9wBH5garqqtubsr4rNCHbGe
% aGqi-C0de9vqqrpepy0dbbL8F4rqqqFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm
% 0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9ad
% biqaceGaciGaciaabiqaceGadaabaaGcbaGaamyAamaaCaaaleqaba
% WaaeWabeaacaWGPbWaaWbaaWqabeaacaWGPbaaaaWccaGLOaGaayzk
% aaaaaOGaaeiiaiabg2da9iaabccacaWGLbWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWade
% qaaiaadwgadaahaaadbeqaaiabgkHiTmaaleaabaGaeqiWdahabaGa
% aGOmaaaacqGHsislcaaIYaGaeqiWdaNaamOBaaaaliabgwSixlaadM
% gacqGHflY1daqadeqaamaaleaameaacqaHapaCaeaacaaIYaaaaSGa
% ey4kaSIaaGOmaiabec8aWjaadUgaaiaawIcacaGLPaaaaiaawUfaca
% GLDbaaaaaaaa!53FD!
$$

My question is: Why does wolframalpha.com shows only the single-valued solution.
In other cases like i^i it shows the multi-valued solutions, too. But only in this cases it don't show the multi-valued solutions. Why?

Comment: I think it's a quirk of WolframAlpha itself. It had shown me single-valued solutions for questions regarding complex numbers too.

Comment: I have learned that  i^(real number) has solutions which all have the same modulus, and (i^i) is a real number. Maybe that is the reason why wolfram do not show all solution. 2) I have the same problem with i^PI : Wolfram show only one solution.